# Maven versions plugin error - org.codehaus.stax2.preserveLocation not supported

Tags: java, maven, version

I'm trying to perform a simple `mvn versions:set` task on the parent module of a large project and get the following error:

```
Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.2:set failed: Property org.codehaus.stax2.preserveLocation is not supported
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.2:set failed: Property org.codehaus.stax2.preserveLocation is not supported
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property org.codehaus.stax2.preserveLocation is not supported
        at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.setProperty(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:246)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.versions.AbstractVersionsUpdaterMojo.newModifiedPomXER(AbstractVersionsUpdaterMojo.java:373)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.versions.AbstractVersionsUpdaterMojo.process(AbstractVersionsUpdaterMojo.java:320)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.versions.SetMojo.execute(SetMojo.java:251)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
```

Maven run with:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T23:58:10+03:00)
Maven home: ...
Java version: 1.8.0_77, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks as if you are using an old version of stax-api. The property `org.codehaus.stax2.preserveLocation` is probably introduced in stax2-api. Are you using stax2-api?

Comment: Yes, apparently it was used by a cfx artifact. Solved the issue by reverting to an older version of the maven-versions-plugin, which was built around stax-api, not stax2-api. Thanx for the tip.